# Where is Preferences.sublime-settings?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I went into Finder, hit Command-F and searched my Mac for `Preferences.sublime-settings` but did not find it.  It found a file I had saved in a non-used folder but did not pull up the actual file that I thought sublime would use.  Where is it?

[image]

I ended up copy pasting the contents of the folder it did find into the sublime application manually.  But I would have preferred to use a hard link to the file.

This is json/javascript file but from the extension you would not know this.

Update - Here is where we think it should be:

[image]

Comment: In `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`, isn't it?

Comment: `USERNAME` is your username, not a literal value.

Comment: I'm quite sure you have a `Library` directory within your users home directory (at least that's the norm) — you likely can't see it because it's ***hidden***.

Comment: `chflags nohidden ~/Library`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

and you will be able to browse Library in your home directory.  You should find the file here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Users
```

Also, you can access this file directly from the Sublime Menu.